# How do I get data from a data table and put it in a variable in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have a simple Login application here. I want it to get the ID of a given username, and see if the password of the same ID matches to know if it should give the user access or not. When I get information out of the table, it has a bunch of other info with it that I don't need. How do I refine this to just the value in the table? (In this example, just the string '

```
string id;
        string login;
        string password;

        string con = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\UserInfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        //Connect to DB
        using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(con))
        {
            //Get ID
            id = connection.Query<string>($"select id from Users where Name = '{txtUsername.Text}'").ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(id);
        }
```

When I run this, I want the message box to display "1", but instead, it says "System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]".

Comment: This code is susceptible to SQL injection. Please use parameterized queries. Beyond that, the first step to troubleshooting this issue is to step through the code in a debugger. You're calling `ToString` on a `List<string>`, that's why the result is the type. You need to retrieve a single entry from the `List<string>` being returned by your query.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error because the Dapper Query method returns an IEnumerable, not a single value

```
  id = connection.Query<string>($"select id from Users where Name = '{txtUsername.Text}'").First();
```

or

```
id = connection.Query<string>($"select id from Users where Name = '{txtUsername.Text}'").Single();
```

try this